# numbers are outside valid range when computing MACD and error handling

Tags: r, error-handling

I'm trying to compute `( MACD - signal ) / signal` of prices of Russel 1000 (which is an index of the 1000 US large cap stocks). I keep getting this error message and simply couldn't figure out why :

> *`Error in EMA(c(49.85, 48.98, 48.6, 49.15, 48.85, 50.1, 50.85, 51.63, 53.5,  :`
> `n = 360 is outside valid range: [1, 198]`*

I'm still relatively new in R although I'm proficient in Python. I suppose I could've used "`try`" to just work around this error, but I do want to understand at least what the cause of it is.

Without further ado, this is the code :

```
N<-1000
DF_t<- data.frame(ticker=rep("", N), macd=rep(NA,N),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)     
stock<-test[['Ticker']]    
i<-0
for (val in stock){dfpx=bdh(c(val), c("px_last"),start.date=as.Date("2018-1- 
01"),end.date=as.Date("2019-12-30"))
macd<- MACD( dfpx[,"px_last"], 60, 360, 45, maType="EMA")
num<-dim(macd)[1]
ma<-(macd[num,][1]-macd[num,][2])/macd[num,][2]
i=i+1 
DF_t[i,]<-list(val,ma)
}
```

For your information,
`bdh()` is a Bloomberg command to fetch historic data.
`dfpx[]` is a dataframe.
`MACD()` is a function that takes a time series of prices and outputs a matrix,
where the first column are the `MACD` values and the second column are the `signal` values.

Thank you very much! Any advice would be really appreciated. Btw, the code works with a small sample of a few stocks but it will cause the error message when I try to apply it to the universe of one thousand stocks. In addition, the number of data points is about 500, which should be large enough for my setup of the parameters to compute MACD.

Comment: Since the code works for small numbers of stocks, wouldn't seem that this is an issue to take up with Bloomberg operations? Maybe your subscription has some limits?

Comment: Thank you! But I doubt that would be the reason. If I request for a static history data made of  1,000 securities with one field which is the closed price, then it would be 1,000*7, which is a lot less than the daily data limit (as far as I remember). I have never personally reached the data limit although I heard that once it happens you should receive something explicit like "NA limit". I still feel this should be a case of error handling. I just can't seem to figure out what causes the error since daily closed price is almost always available. I still appreciate your comment nonetheless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Q** : *"...and error handling"*

If I may add a grain of salt onto this, the error-prevention is way better than any ex-post error-handling.

For this, there is a cheap, constant O(1) in both `[TIME]`- and `[SPACE]`-Domains step, that principally prevents any such error-related crashes :

Just prepend to the instantiated the vector of TimeSERIES data with that many constant and process-invariant value cells, that make it to the maximum depth of any vector-processing, and any such error or exception is principally avoided :

- processing-invariant value, in most cases, is the first know value, to be repeated that many times, as needed back, in the direction of time towards older ( not present ) bars <sub>( yes, not relying on `NaN`-s and how `NaN`-s might get us in troubles in methods, that are sensitive to missing data, which was described above. Q.E.D. )</sub>

Comment: Sorry, I just happened to see this answer. I really don't understand how it is related to my question directly though. Are you suggesting always try to seek prevention than ex-post handling? In other words, always make sure you have addressed missing value issue before even trying to run any code?

Answer (score 0):

For those who are interested, I have found the cause of the error: some stocks have missing prices. It's simple like that. For instance, Dow US Equity has only about 180 daily prices (for whatever reason) over the past one and a half years, which definitely can't be used to compute a moving average of 360 days.

I basically ran small samples till I eventually pinpointed what caused the error message. Generally speaking, unless you are trying to extract data of above 6,000 stocks or so and you are querying say 50 fields, you are Okay. A rule of thumb for daily usage limit of Bloomberg is said to be around 500,000 for a school console. A PhD colleague working in a trading firm also told me professional consoles of Bloomberg are more forgiving.